# Why does populating my table take so long?

Tags: python, mysql, cgi

I'm loading a csv file into my database via a web form.

The order of the raw data is consistent in each csv file, but it changes from file to file, depending on the source, so I have a preview form that shows five rows and allows you to assign a column via a drop-down list of valid column names in the table.

Then I use the cgi form to build an INSERT statement, and parse the csv file line-by-line to populate the table.

But it is running EXTREMELY slow. I'm concurrently populating two tables, one with 961402 rows (7 columns with values), and the other with 1835538 rows(1 column with values), and each has been running for at least half an hour. I'm only seeing something like 100 new rows per second.

Can you see anything here that would slow me down?

NOTE: I know there is some ugly code in here, it was one of the first python cgi scripts I wrote while figuring this language out.

```
 for item in form:
          field = form.getvalue(item)
          field = cgi.escape(field)
          if field == 'null':
                  pass
          elif item == 'csvfile':
                  pass
          elif item == 'campaign':
                  pass
          elif item == 'numfields':
                  pass
          else:
                  colname = str(colname) + ", " + str(item)

                  colnum.append(field)
  assert(numfields > 0)
  placeholders = (numfields-1) * "%s, " + "%s"
  query = ("insert into %s (%s)" % (table, colname.lstrip(",")))
  with open(fname, 'rb') as f:
          reader = csv.reader(f)
          try:
                  record = 0
                  errors = 0
                  for row in reader:
                          try:
                                  record = record + 1
                                  data = ''
                                  for value in colnum:
                                          col = int(value)
                                          rawrow = row[col]
                                          saferow = rawrow.replace("'", "-")
                                          saferow = saferow.replace("-", "")
                                          data = str(data) + ", '" + saferow + "'"
                                  dataset = data.lstrip(',')
                                  insert = query + (" values (%s)" % dataset)
                                  cur.execute(insert)
                                  con.commit()
                                  print ".",
                          except IndexError, e:
                                  print "Row:%d file %s, %s<br>" % (reader.line_num, fname.lstrip("./files/"), e)
                                  errors = errors + 1
                          except csv.Error, e:
                                  print "Row:%s file %s, line %d: %s<br>" % (record, fname, reader.line_num, e)
                                  errors = errors + 1
                          except mdb.Error, e:
                                  print "Row:%s Error %d: %s<br>" % (record, e.args[0], e.args[1])
                                  errors = errors + 1
                          except:
                                  t,v,tb = sys.exc_info()
                                  print "Row:%s %s<br>" % (record, v)
                                  errors = errors + 1
          except csv.Error, e:
                  print "except executed<br>"
                  sys.exit('file %s, line %d: %s' % (fname, reader.line_num, e))
  print "Succesfully loaded %s into Campaign %s, <br>" % (fname.lstrip("./files/"), table)
  print record - errors, "new records.<br>"
  print errors, "errors.<br>"
```

EDIT/UPDATE: Using `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` worked like a charm, I loaded up 600K records in less than a minute.

New Code is cleaner, too.

```
    else:
            colnum.append([field, item])
sortlist =  sorted(colnum, key=itemgetter(0))
cols = ''
for colname in sortlist:
    cols = cols + "%s, " % colname[1]
cur.execute("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '%s' IGNORE INTO TABLE %s FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (%s)" % (fname, table, cols.rstrip(', ')))
con.commit()
```

The only catch is that I have to do a smidge more work preparing my csv files to ensure data integrity, otherwise, works like a charm.

Comment: Please remove the line numbers - they just make it harder to work with.

Comment: INSERT INTO sql queries into large tables can be a pretty slow operation.  Try creating a file full of INSERT INTOs and run it through your sql client manually to see what I mean.

Comment: that's what I'm thinking, @paul, but THIS slow? between the two, 200 records a second just seems to be crawling. Is there any way to speed it up? The columns are all CHAR data types.

Comment: sounds about right to me.  If you have indexes on the table they have to be maintained as you write and so the writes take longer the more rows are in the table.

Comment: You should probably be using `executemany`, passing all your rows as a parameter, and then commiting the entire insert.  See an example here http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#id11.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski wouldn't that still execute each insert individually?  I would save time on the commit, but looks like it will still cost for 1.8 million inserts.

Comment: @TaoJoannes:  The Python Database API Specification v2.0 states that `executemany` can be implemented "using multiple calls to the .execute() method or by using array operations to have the database process the sequence as a whole in one call."  So it's implementation dependent.  It's worth trying to see how it performs.  If it performs badly then using mysqlimport would be the next logical step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

INSERT INTO, done one row at a time, is pretty slow considering that some SQLs, like mySQL, support either having a bunch of rows on a single insert command or LOAD DATA statements that can read CSV files quickly into the server.

See also:  https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16809/why-is-load-data-infile-faster-than-normal-insert-statements

Comment: After your comment above, I started looking into mysqlimport. I'm thinking I can build the column names as I do currently, then just import the csv file all at once. Something to try once I finish this run, at least.

Answer (score 1):

Some quick pseudocode. Do this:

```
for row in data_to_be_inserted:
    stmt = compose_statement("lalala")
    cursor.execute()

connection.commit()
```

not

```
for row in data_to_be_inserted:
    stmt = compose_statement("lalala")
    cursor.execute()
    connection.commit()
```

Your code commit()s once per line of input. That slows it down significantly.

Comment: I added that in due to the processing time, I was having an issue where it took so long apache gave up on serving the page. With the extra commits, it persists.